# Does 'noel' really have its origin in Latin?

Tags: etymology

This arises from the question by @brianpck about the meaning of ‘noe’ in the context of Christmas, which he ended with a speculation about noel/nowell being shortened from the Hebrew *emmanuel* (God is with us) — which I had heard before and am inclined to favour.

I am well aware that dictionaries give an etymology based on *nascor, nasci, (g)natus* and/or the adjectives *natalis* or *natalicius* Even allowing for a variant *nael* postulated by Etymonline I don't find this convincing, especially as the dictionaries that I have looked at all seem (lazily?) to use very nearly the same form of words. I wonder if someone is able to explain just how such an origin can be supported: I can’t for the life of me see how some part of nascor, etc, could turn into words for Christmas that have only the letter 'n' in common. I confess to much ignorance about vowel shifts and so on, but this seems to be stretching things a bit too far.

Comment: It's funny, a friend asked me the same thing about how *natalis* could possible change to *noel*. I muttered something about how maybe there's a rule that let's a dental disappear between two vowels, but I've never studied linguistics formally, so it was just speculation.

Comment: etymonline and other on-line English dictionaries are all copied (or rather pasted) from other dictionaries. The CNRTL by contrast is a serious academic source. Please note that Old French nael is not "postulated" but attested (see the first quotation in the CNRTL entry).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the etymology of [Noel (Ortolang)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/noel):

> Étymol. et Hist. A. Subst. masc. 1. début xiies. «fête de la nativité de Jésus-Christ» al Naël Deu (Saint Brendan, 620, éd. E. G. R. Waters); 1119 Noel (Philippe de Thaon, Comput, 53, éd. E. Mall); 1694 busche de Noel «grosse bûche que l'on mettait dans l'âtre pour toute la nuit de Noël» (Ac.); 1845 arbre de Noël (Besch.); 1855 père Noël (Sand., loc. cit.); 1949 croire au père Noël (Sartre, loc. cit.); 2. 1178 «époque où l'on célèbre Noël» (Roman de Renart, Br. XII, 13311, éd. M. Roques: Ce fu un pou devant Noel Que l'on metoit bacons en sel); 1611 à Noel au perron, à Pâques au tison (Cotgr.); 3. ca 1300 «cri de réjouissance que poussait le peuple» (Guillaume de La Villeneuve, Les Crieries du peuple, 109 ds Fabliaux et Contes, éd. E. Barbazan, II, 282); 4. 1548 «cantique chanté à l'occasion des fêtes de Noël» (Rabelais, Ancien Prologue du Quart Livre, éd. R.Marichal, p.287). B. Subst. fém. 1813 (J.-F. Rolland, Dict. mauv. lang., p.93). Du lat. natalis adj. «de naissance, relatif à la naissance», natalis dies et par substantivation natalis «jour de naissance» utilisé en lat. eccl. pour désigner la Nativité du Christ. **L'o de noël (en face de l'a. fr. nael, ital. natale, a. prov. nadal) est dû à une dissimilation des 2 a de natalis.**

(The bold-facing is mine).

In brief: the loss of /t/ between two vowels is normal in French (as in pater > père). Latin natalis > Old French naël. The alternative form noël implies natalis > *notalis, with dissimilation of a-a to o-a.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to settle it. However, I think there may be another origin for Nowell in the English carol, which is possibly 14th C — but we'll let it pass!

Comment: *The alternative form noël implies natalis > *notalis*: more likely the dissimilation followed the consonant loss, given the attested form *nael*.

Comment: @TKR. That is the part I am not sure about. You cannot very well argue that nael > noel is the result of dissimilation. It is more likely that natalis > naël and natalis > *notalis > noël are two different dialect forms, of which the latter prevailed.

Comment: *You cannot very well argue that nael > noel is the result of dissimilation* -- why not?

Comment: @TKR. Because the vowels in naël are not similar.

Comment: Dissimilation just means segments become less similar -- they don't have to start out identical.

Comment: To echo another of your comments, _DHLF/Rey_ says around 1112, with an explanation similar to the one from the _Trésor_. Here's a [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=yqM-AAAAYAAJ&dq=comput%20thaon%20Eduard%20Mall&pg=PA119#v=onepage&q&f=false) to the 1119 _Comput_ reprod. edited by Eduard Mall referenced in your quote. Also, always interesting, the [_FEW_](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/179479)...

Answer (score 3):

I just came across [this fantastic song/video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3uPfGELT4Y) explaining the etymology of noël (and nowell along the way) from Latin *natalis*.  He covers loss of final syllables, dissimulation, and vocalic changes (distinctive to French).

As the chorus goes,

> Noël, noël, noël, noël
>
> was Latin for birthday
>
> but now you can't tell

It is very, very clever and well worth two and half minutes of your time!

Comment: Thank you, that is brilliant! (his Biblical Philologist to the tune of 'Modern Major General' by G&S is also worth a listen).

Comment: @TomCotton It was the Biblical Philologist that first introduced me to him!  It's a masterpiece!